# Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and the desktop environment doesn't seem to be rendering properly

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, graphics, themes

I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 but windows seem to be missing graphical components:
[image: missing graphical components]

I have tried the following

- Reinstalling Ubuntu desktop with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  ```
- Using another desktop environment (Xfce) - same kind
  of issues.
- Installing the latest drivers: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` says

  ```
  No drivers found for this installation.
  ```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a custom theme (Flatabulous) which stopped working with the 18.04 upgrade. See the [issue on this](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous/issues/153).

I had tried changing the theme with lxappearance but this didn't fix the problem. Using gnome-tweak-tool did.